# Magento 2.1.0 Paypal checkout gives server error when returning from paypal

Tags: magento-2.1

I've configured paypal payments standard in payment methods. When I go to checkout it goes to paypal website, I click pay and tries to return to my website but it throws and error (HTTP 500). I enabled paypal debugging and captured the response and it looks ok to me. I checked cpanel errors and I do see an error every time I try to pay with paypal.

> Sat Dec 03 05:00:58.755401 2016] [access_compat:error] [pid 26474:tid
>   140193401718528] [client 216.172.xxx.xxx:37462] AH01797: client denied
>   by server configuration:
>   /home/mywebsite/public_html/app/etc/config.php

I looked into this post
[Client denied by server configuration /app/etc/config.php](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/104599/client-denied-by-server-configuration-app-etc-config-php)

I disabled the `.htaccess` to see if that was the issue but I'm still getting the error 500. The error didn't show in my cpanel though. I've since re-enabled `.htaccess`.

I've looked in the exceptions log and there isn't any useful info in there regarding my issue.

Is there any place else to check for troubleshooting this issue?

---

I've troubleshot a few more settings and found if I set "Skip Order Review Step" to No, It will come back from paypal ok. Then when I click the button to place order I get the 500 error.

This also happens both when trying to check out as guest and a registered user.